# Unable to deploy Contact Page Backend in Node.js to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I wrote backend in Node.js for the contact page on my portfoilio on Firebase. I'm trying to deploy it, but when open the app, it gives me an 'Application Error'. When I go to the logs, it gives me `error code=H10 desc="App crashed"`.

Update: I also see an error `Error: Cannot find module '@sendGrid/mail'`.

I've tried a few things. I added `"start": "node App.js"` and `"engines": { "node": "12.13.1" }` to my `package.json`. I created a Procfile with `web: node App.js`. In my `App.js`, I changed my `app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');` to `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);`.

I'm not sure if I have to set `process.env.PORT` to something. How would I fix this?

#### Relevant Code

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express'); //Needed to launch server.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); //Needed to disable sendgrid security.
const sendGrid = require('@sendGrid/mail'); //Access SendGrid library to send emails.
sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const app = express(); //Alias from the express function.

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('API Status: Running');
});

app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const msg = {
        to: 'my@email.com',
        from: req.body.email,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    }
    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });
        });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

Also, here's my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node App.js"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Zhang",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Also, here are the Application Logs:

```
2020-08-30T14:49:33.088197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-30T14:49:35.380821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-30T14:49:35.420886+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328408+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328435+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328436+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328436+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328437+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '@sendGrid/mail'
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328437+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328437+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328438+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328438+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:4:18)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328440+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328441+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328441+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328441+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328442+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
2020-08-30T14:49:35.328442+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-08-30T14:49:46.278674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api" host=daniel-zhang-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=b50170d2-6e1f-4697-aa35-3ea445d1d936 fwd="75.75.104.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-30T14:49:46.490432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=daniel-zhang-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=cb1bdef2-0cb6-400d-aaf5-e8e2c2b8fa35 fwd="75.75.104.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Also here's my file structure:

[image: File Structure]

Comment: I dont see anything jumping out at me in your code, have you followed the heroku guide for deploying nodejs apps? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: I entered `git add .`, `git commit -am "make it better"`, and `git push heroku master` when I deploy.

Comment: have you added environment variables from your code to heroku? or are you loading environment variables from the start script / dotenv?

Comment: right now nodejs is requiring SENDGRID_API_KEY and PORT from process.env, you will either need to add those variables in your package.json file under the start script (i highly recommend not doing that), or adding to heroku's env

Comment: I just added SENDGRID_API_KEY and PORT as 4000 to Heroku in config vars. it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: according to your logs it looks like an issue with your folder tree, it looks to be loading your app file with /app/App.js, one of our old heroku apps starts with "node src/index.js"

Comment: I changed App.js to index.js, but it didn't seem to do anything. I also noticed an error message with **Error: Cannot find module '@sendGrid/mail'**.

Comment: try dropping your index file inside a src folder then referencing it in your package.json as "node /src/index.js"

Comment: That didn't work either, it gave me **Error: Cannot find module '/src/index.js'**. I feel liek it has to do with the `Error: Cannot find module '@sendGrid/mail'`, but I'm not sure what. It's listed in the dependencies.

Comment: are you doing a gitignore and preventing node_modules from being added? Heroku also supports using a build pack, which will tell heroku to build your app when you upload it

Comment: I have not considered that, how do I do that?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: I've been using the heroku/nodejs buildpack the whole time. How would I use a gitignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `const sendGrid = require('@sendGrid/mail');`, `'@sendGrid/mail'` should be `'@sendgrid/mail'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer because I was getting the same error message. However, the issue was not related to the case import/require statement.

The error i was facing was following (Error: Cannot find module '@sendgrid/mail')

[image]

However, my application was running locally without any errors, as @sendgrid/mail was present inside my node_modules folder.

[image]

**So what was the culprit?**

Thw issue was inside my **package.json** file, as it was not present inside it as a dependency.

**Solution**

I ran the following commands inside my Vs code terminal.

```
npm install @sendgrid/mail
git add .
git commit -m "my fix"
git push heroku master
```

Note: you may update the push command according to your branch, in my case it was master.